# Can we ever scale elliptic curve points?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elliptic-curves

When does scaling an elliptic curve point align with the standard notion of scaling coordinate points?

Let $P = (x_0,y_0)$ be a point on an elliptic curve $E$ over a prime $p$. When can we find $n$ and $\lambda$ so that

$$nP = (\lambda x_0, \lambda y_0)$$

where $nP$ is normal elliptic curve multiplication? (We can span all the points for suitable $n$ and generator $P$ but I'm looking for specific constructions of for $n$)

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with [tag:group-theory].

Comment: The points on a curve are a group.

Comment: So do vectors in a vector space. We don't need the [tag:group-theory] tag for every linear algebra question.